# Network card not starting automatically

Tags: networking, 18.04, server, startup

My network card on my Ubuntu server 18.04 LTS does not start up automatically on boot.This only happened after I tried editing some files which were responsible for starting scripts on boot.I was searching for commands on the internet and realized that when I typed the following my network card showed up again:

> ip link set dev enp4s0 up
>   dhclient enp4s0

'enp4s0'  is my card.

I am new to Linux and I do not know what is causing this problem. Please help.

Comment: Assuming you edited files from the CLI/command line, have you looked at what you did using `history` (ie. BASH's command history). I wouldn't try and resolve the problem as much as reverse what you did (so you don't have problems down the line in upgrades, or release-upgrade time).

Comment: I created /etc/rc.local as it was not there and then did chmod +x to it. Then I did systemctl enable rc.local.After this I shut down my server and the next time it booted I got this problem. I thought that rc.local was the cause and deleted the file.